# How to auto backup set directories to ext hard disk upon docking computer?

Tags: backup, docking-station

I have a slight problem, my computers hard disk is quite small so it get's filled up quite fast.

Luckily I have 2TB external hard disc, however copying files to it constantly is a pain.
 I was wondering if there is any script that I could use that will back up directories that I have chosen from my computers hard disc onto the external drive upon connecting to the dock?

Comment: What OS?  Are you talking about a one-time command or something run periodically?  If the latter, this is a fundamental backup function and there are endless existing scripts, utilities, and applications, many free, that do this.  Is there a reason you can't use one of those?  You can even Google to find numerous evaluations, comparisons, and recommendations.  Is the issue that it needs to be triggered by connecting to the dock?

Comment: yes this is exactly the issue, I want it to be triggered the I connect to the dock rather than a time schedule or something else

Comment: A thought: you haven't gotten a response on this, and it may be because the focus is on the backup.  People may be viewing this as a request for a software recommendation, which is off-topic.  That aspect may actually be somewhat irrelevant to the real issue.  Most backup software can be configured with the specifics of the job, so you simply need to run it; i.e., it's just a program.  The real question is how to trigger the execution of a program by connecting to the dock.  If you reframe the question along those lines (and identify the computer, dock, and OS), you may get a better response.